# Reactive form: How to capture the input value into a variable within component using FormControl on Angular WITHOUT [(ngModel)]?

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms, angular-validation, form-control

I have a simple text input on my web-app front-end Angular that takes in a userName:

```
<div [formGroup]="userNameFormGroupEnquiry">    
<mat-form-field>
      <mat-label>Chosen Name:</mat-label>
      <input name="chosenName" formControlName="chosenName" [(ngModel)]="chosenName" matInput type="text" placeholder="JOHN DOE"/>
      <mat-hint align="end">REQUIRED FIELD!</mat-hint>
      <mat-error *ngIf="hasNameError('chosenName', 'required')"
        >Minimum and Maxmimum of length 12 is required!</mat-error
      >
    </mat-form-field>
</div>
```

I use formGroup because i intend to add in more input fields into this div, just wanna get this input to work first.

I used `[(ngModel)]="chosenName"`to capture the input value and assign it to a variable in my Component class (`this.chosenName`).

My Component below:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-user',
  templateUrl: './userInput.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./userInput.component.scss']
})
export class UserInputEnquiry implements OnInit {
  title = 'Welcome to this note-taking app!';
  chosenName: string;
  enquiryByUserInputForm: FormGroup;

  constructor() {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.enquiryByUserInputForm = new FormGroup({
      chosenName: new FormControl('', [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(9), Validators.maxLength(9)])
    });
  }

  public hasLengthError = (controlName: string, errorName: string) => {
    return this.enquiryByUserInputForm.controls[controlName].hasError(errorName);
  };

  onSubmit() {
      console.log(this.chosenName);
  }

}
```

As per my previous question's answer, I was told not to use `[(ngModel)]` since FormControl already encompasses Input capturing and i get a pretty severe warning, but how so?

If i remove `[(ngModel)]="chosenName"` from the input, the input never gets captured for `this.chosenName` and the console logs an blank/undefined output. Is there something I'm missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want any initial value then initialize `chosenName` with that.

```
chosenName: string = '';
```

Then you can initialize the form with this value:

```
this.enquiryByUserInputForm = new FormGroup({
  chosenName: new FormControl(this.chosenName, [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(9), Validators.maxLength(9)])
});
```

On submit, you can access all the form values using:

```
  onSubmit() {
      console.log(this.enquiryByUserInputForm.value);
  }
```

To get a specific control value, you can do:

```
  onSubmit() {
      console.log(this.enquiryByUserInputForm.get('chosenName').value);
  }
```

**EDIT:**
*`chosenName` class property can be completely omitted as it just serves the purpose of initialization and this you can do directly when creating the form.*

Comment: This solved my question with the this.enquiryByUserInputForm.get('chosenName').value line :) Thanks for the help man!

Answer (score 0):

If you are using ReactiveFormsModule, you can subscribe to the value changes.

```
this.userNameFormGroupEnquiry.valueChanges.subscribe(values => do something)
```

values will be an object where { formcontrolname: valueofinput}

That will fire every time any of the inputs change, too often. So there are a few things you can do to control things.

```
this.userNameFormGroupEnquiry.valueChanges.pipe(
     filter(() => this.userNameFormGroupEnquiry.valid && 
                  this.userNameFormGroupEnquiry.dirty),
     debounceTime(1000))
    .subscribe(values => do something)
```

This checks for changes and validity in the form, and debounces; meaning it will emit a second after the last keystroke. This still fires often, and there is another thing you can do.

When you define the form controls, you do something like this:

```
this.userNameFormGroupEnquiry = new FormGroup( {
    chosenName: new FormControl('', { updateOn: 'blur', validators: 
              Validators.required }),
    ...
    })
```

The updateOn can be set to 'change' | 'blur' | 'submit'.

In a complex and large form this can easily turn into a firehose, but there are a few options available to limit the flow to something manageable.

Answer (score 0):

> Best approach to capture input value into a variable in Angular
> reactive form:

```
chosenName: string = '';

ngOnInit() {
    this.enquiryByUserInputForm = this.formBuilder.group({
        chosenName: new FormControl(null, [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(9), Validators.maxLength(9)])
    });
}

get getFc() {
    return this.enquiryByUserInputForm.controls;
}

onSubmit() {
    this.chosenName = this.getFc['chosenName'].value
    console.log(this.chosenName);
}
```